# GraphQL + firebase questions

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, graphql

I have been losing all Saturday trying to figure out this. I am good in frontend and decided to jump in and learn back end as well. I have been very interested in graphQl and since I was already doing a lot with firebase it was a go. 
I decided to learn the graphQl server but cannot figure out what I am doing wrong.

I have this resolver to create a firebase account:

```
module.exports = {
  Mutation: {
    registerUser: async (
      _,
      { registerInput: { username, email, password } },
      context,
      info
    ) => {


      const register = await admin
        .auth()
        .createUser({
          email,
          emailVerified: false,
          password: password,
          displayName: username,
          disabled: false
        })
        .then(function(userRecord) {
          console.log("Successfully created new user:", userRecord.uid);
           const {userData} = admin
             .firestore()
             .collection("users")
             .doc(userRecord.uid)
             .set(
               {
                 email,
                 role: "user",
                 username,
                 uid: userRecord.uid
             }, {merge: true});
            return register
        })
        .catch(function(error) {
            console.log("Error creating new user:", error);
        });
        return register
    }
```

and in the schema:

```
type Mutation {
    registerUser(registerInput: RegisterInput): User!

type User {
     firstName: String
     lastName: String
    password: String!
     adress: String
     postCode: String
     role: String
     ort: String
    email: String!
     phone: String
     responseRate: Float
     responseTime: Int
     profilePicture: String
     token: String
    username: String!
     personnummer: Int
  }

input RegisterInput{
  username: String!
  email: String!
  password: String!
}
```

However when I run it in the playground, sometimes the account and the document about the user gets created, other times doesn't, but I always get the same error on the playground:

```
"errors": [
    {
      "message": "Cannot return null for non-nullable field Mutation.registerUser.",
      "locations": [
        {
          "line": 2,
          "column": 3
        }
      ],
      "path": [
        "registerUser"
      ],
      "extensions": {
        "code": "INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR",
        "exception": {
          "stacktrace": [
            "Error: Cannot return null for non-nullable field Mutation.registerUser.",
            "    at completeValue
```

Answer (score 1):

Your resolver is an async function, so it will always return a Promise, but that promise will resolve to whatever is returned inside the function. If you return `undefined` or `null`, then the field in question (`registerUser`) will resolve to null. Since you've told GraphQL that can't happen, it throws an error to that effect.

When you call `then` on a Promise, whatever is returned inside `then`'s callback becomes the value the Promise resolves to (provided no errors are thrown that would cause the Promise to reject). What you're returning inside the `then` callback in your code is `register`, which is effectively undefined because it's being used before being initialized.

If you're already using async/await syntax, there's no point in continuing to use `then`. Just stick with `await` -- it will keep your code cleaner, easier to read and less error-prone.

```
const userRecord = await admin
  .auth()
  .createUser({...})

// if `set` returns a Promise, we should await that as well
const { userData } = await admin
  .firestore()
  .collection("users")
  .doc(userRecord.uid)
  .set(...)

return userData
```

Note that GraphQL will catch any errors or rejected Promises for you and surface them as part of the response, so you don't need to use try/catch here *unless* you want to mask or otherwise format the error.

Comment: thanks man! I actually had among those, other errors and was not thinking it was a promise that was returned, needless to say, i fixed it. 

Now I am struggling with the login part, where I need to find a way to compare passwords, but that is entirely firebase admin sdk stuff.